# ostream and istream overlaloading without << / >> operator

Tags: c++, overloading, comma-operator

Whenever I use **cout** and **cin**, I have to use 3 key (shift,2 press < <) .

I tryed to overloading ostream and istream with `,` (comma operator) .

And now everything works well, except **cin** on `int`,`float`,`double`,`char` but it works with `char[]`. also I tested `tie()` method to tie ostream to istream but stream of cin does not tie to stream of cout.

In fact cin get value but the value does not tie to cout.

thanks so much if you have an idea.

```
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::endl;


template < class AT> // AT : All Type 
std::ostream& operator,(std::ostream& out,AT t)
{
    out<<t;
    return out;
}
template < class AT> // AT : All Type 
std::istream& operator,(std::istream& in,AT t)
{
    in>>t;
    return in;
}

int main(){
    cout,"stack over flow\n";
    const char* sof ( "stack over flow\n" );
    cout,sof;

    char sof2[20] ("stack over flow\n");
    cout,sof2;

    int i (100);
    float f (1.23);
    char ch ('A');
    cout,"int i = ",i,'\t',",float f = ",f,'\t',",char ch = ",ch,'\n';
    cout,"\n_____________________\n";
    cin,sof2;  /// okay, it works
    cout,sof2; /// okay, it works
    cin,i;     /// okay it works
    cout,i;    /// does not work. does not tie to cin
}
```

### output

> ```
> stack over flow
> stack over flow
> stack over flow
> int i = 100   ,float f = 1.23 ,char ch = A
>
> _____________________
> hello // cin,sof2;  /// okay, it works
> hello
> 50   // cin,i;     /// okay it works
> 100  // does not work and return the first value the smae is 100
>
>
> Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 15.586 s
> Press ENTER to continue.
> ```

by : g++ 5.2.1.

if you wnat to test this code, your gun c++ must be 5.2 or upper; or change `()` initialize to `=`

for compile on command-line

> **`g++ -std=c++14 -O2 -Wall -pedantic -pthread main.cpp`**

Comment: Please don't do this. You will confuse other developers when they come across your code.

Comment: `printf` requires you to type the string formatting and values separately. `print`s in most languages require individual calls per value (even the streams in C++, but they're masked behind those 3 keys). I think that typing 3 keys is not going to hurt your fingers more than the people reading your code.

Comment: it is for fun and no serious @graham.reeds

Comment: if you use comma for both input and output, operation on iostreams will be ambiguous

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You code doesn't work for int, float, double, char because in your >> operator you pass argument by value, not by reference. Change it in this way:

```
template < class AT> // AT : All Type 
std::istream& operator,(std::istream& in, AT& t)
{
    in>>t;
    return in;
}
```

But as graham.reeds already stated, it's a bad idea to replace << and >> operators with comma in this way, it will mess your code.

Comment: Just a reference? Not a const reference?

Comment: @Qwertiy what are you on about? `const AT&` will not work for `in >> t`;

Comment: x-value reference is better for the cout version.

Comment: Of course, const reference is not an option, because you're changing the value, you're reding it from cin.

Comment: Sorry, I thought about `cout`. Seems it would be better to pass const reference there.

Comment: By the way, `return in >> t;`

Answer (score 1):

This will 'fix' it:

```
template < class AT> // AT : All Type
std::ostream& operator,(std::ostream& out,AT&& t)
{
    out<<t;
    return out;
}
template < class AT> // AT : All Type
std::istream& operator,(std::istream& in,AT&& t)
{
    in>>t;
    return in;
}
```

Just checking, but you do know that this is your worst idea yet, right?

Comment: for the output operation in the general case a const reference would be the standard approach, why an x-value reference?

Comment: because it will work for any object reference (const or not) and any temporary.

Comment: @k-five really? it worked in my test. What version of c++ are you using? What are you specifying on the command line? I have -std=c++14

Comment: @RichardHodges Hi. well you have to use `g++ -std=c++14 -O2 -Wall -pedantic -pthread`